# Laravel - Adding a country drop down list to Jetstream profile

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm very new to MVC development and Laravel. I try to learn by reading a lot and watching tutorials. I'm currently working on a small Laravel project and installed the Jetstream/Livewire scaffolding.
I'd like the user to be able to select their country when he is on his profile page (app.test/user/profile).
I've managed to add extra input fields but can't figure out what to if i want to get my drop down populated with my db data.

So far i've managed to create my countries table and seed it with a seeder file.
I can locate the view where i have to add my select field.
However, arrived here, I'm completly stucked...how can I retrieve my country list from db as I don't see/figure out how my model, view and route should interact together. I don't find any controller also.

So far, i have the below model: Country.php

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Models;
  
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  
class Country extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
  
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'code'
    ];
}
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, while digging i could find answer to my questio:

```
  <div wire:model.defer="state.country_id" class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
    <x-jet-label for="country_id" value="{{ __('Country') }}" />
    <select name="country_id" class="px-3 py-2 block mt-1 w-full border-gray-300 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-md shadow-sm">
        
        @foreach (\App\Models\Country::all() as $country)
            <option value="{{  $country->id }}"
            @if ($country->id == Auth::user()->country_id)
                selected="selected"                                   
            @endif
            >{{ $country->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <x-jet-input-error for="country_id" class="mt-2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide more of an explanation on what your code does and how it helped with the question?